# Landscape view issues (layout debug methods)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I assume it's a plugin that sucks here. When I switch to the landscape View in eclipse I get something like this:
http://img718.imageshack.us/img718/1239/landscape1je.jpg

Of course it doesn't bring to mind typical 4inch screen. So there is no way to check how is the ScrollView working in the eclipse?

Ok, so i send the app to the phone. And here is a trouble. When I turn the phone to the landscape I get this:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/718/landscape3x.jpg/

And this is the most top scroll I can get. This image shows the scrollable area:
http://img849.imageshack.us/img849/2774/landscape2y.jpg

And this is my xml code. I would do that usual way of try and mistakes but sending an app to the phone every time makes it really long :/ Maybe I can get some help here faster

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="30dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add_income"
            android:layout_width="120dip"
            android:layout_height="120dip"
            android:layout_margin="15dip"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon_income"
            android:text="@string/income" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add_expense"
            android:layout_width="120dip"
            android:layout_height="120dip"
            android:layout_margin="15dip"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon_expense"
            android:text="@string/expense" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/categories"
            android:layout_width="120dip"
            android:layout_height="120dip"
            android:layout_margin="15dip"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon_category"
            android:text="@string/categories" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/summary"
            android:layout_width="120dip"
            android:layout_height="120dip"
            android:layout_margin="15dip"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon_summary"
            android:text="@string/summary" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/charts"
            android:layout_width="120dip"
            android:layout_height="120dip"
            android:layout_margin="15dip"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon_charts"
            android:text="@string/charts" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bug_list"
            android:layout_width="120dip"
            android:layout_height="120dip"
            android:layout_margin="15dip"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon_bug"
            android:text="@string/bugs" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you designed this xml separately for landscape and placed it in layout-land folder? And yeah, you can test scrolling in eclipse like you usually do - just scroll. It has worked for me.

Comment: first image link doesn't work...

Comment: I didn't design it separately. i didn't know about this. And I dont have  anything to scroll, as the 1st image shows (I corrected the link).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case (I'm adding it as an answer here instead of a comment), you've to design layouts separately for landscape mode and place those layouts in `res/layout-land`. But do keep in mind - naming conventions for the layouts should be the same. For example: `setContentView(R.layout.main);` by default loads the `portrait layout`. So when you turn the phone and `landscape layout` appears, android will automatically fetch xml from your `layout-land` folders. So, `setContentView(R.layout.main);` this time loads the xml from that folder. While designing the layout itself, you should make the graphical editor to appear in `landscape` mode so that it's easier for design. Try this.

Comment: cool, but still I don't have a decent preview for the landscape layout. It's like on the first screenshot :/

Comment: Try Relative Layout. Usually helps. And one more thing - keep in mind the design aspects when you're designing landscape versions.

Comment: you're right, I get the proper resolution now. Well, still can't scroll but it's going somewhere

Comment: Try nesting the entire thing inside a Scroll View. Since it's a landscape layout, I think a horizontal scroll view would be better.